# How to get Server IP on Android?

Tags: android, sockets, ip, spotify, server

I'm programming a little application based on Spotify's Android SDK. I have to get some parameters of the spotify session in an android device and then send them to another Android device via Socket. In order to do this, I need to know the server's IP address, which can change depending on the location. Is this possible in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: The servers ip address of which server? Depending on the location of?

Comment: I will have two devices: one working as the client and the other one as server. Since they are mobile, they can connect to different networks, so the ip will change depending on the network. I guess I will have to ask the user to introduce the server's ip on the client side manually, but can you think of an automatic solution?

Comment: Your mobile provider will mostly not support you running servers on your phone.  `they can connect to different networks`. You mean mobile networks? Not wifi networks? If your mobile provider allows it then you need an internet server somewhere where your devices server puts its ip addres which the client can request.

Comment: I meant both mobile and wifi networks, but mostly wifi. 

Finally I decided that the user in the client part introduces the IP of the server.

Anyway, programming the server is being a pain. I want to receive a file on the server, do you know any tutorial or example to do so? I have been looking in stack overflow and mostly i find tutorial for sending messages, but not files.

Comment: What kind of difference would there be between sending messages and filed?

Comment: Examples of client/server code to transfer files over socket are many on stackoverflow.